# Python - 3D affine transformation

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, config-transformation

I am working with two similar shaped, but not yet identical volumes with a volume grid inside. I am aiming to match my first volume (green) to my second volume (red).
Both have a ConvexHull ([http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html](http://scipy.spatial.ConvexHull)) with inner vertices. I created multiple marker (see Figure 1) for both volumes to calculate a transformation matrix([https://community.esri.com/thread/183601-numpy-linalglstsq-coordinate-translations)](http://calculating%20the%20trans_mat).

The Volume Grid Data structure of my original volume is:

```
array([[ 0.025, -0.055, -0.03 ],
       [-0.01 , -0.05 , -0.03 ],
       [-0.005, -0.05 , -0.03 ],
       ..., 
       [-0.01 , -0.03 ,  0.1  ],
       [-0.01 , -0.025,  0.1  ],
       [-0.015, -0.02 ,  0.1  ]])

 ,     with the shape of `(12163, 3)`
```

The Volume Grid Data structure of my original volume is:

```
array([[ 0.   , -0.055, -0.065],
       [ 0.005, -0.055, -0.065],
       [-0.005, -0.05 , -0.065],
       ..., 
       [-0.005, -0.02 ,  0.08 ],
       [ 0.   , -0.02 ,  0.08 ],
       [ 0.005, -0.02 ,  0.08 ]])

 ,     with the shape of `(14629, 3)`
```

[image: Figure 1 - Marker for both ConvexHull Volumes]

The coordinates of the original markers which should be transformed are:

```
array([[-0.00307161, -0.01828496,  0.03521746],
       [-0.065     , -0.01828496,  0.03521746],
       [ 0.06      , -0.01828496,  0.03521746],
       [-0.00307161, -0.01828496,  0.1       ],
       [-0.00307161,  0.075     ,  0.03521746],
       [-0.00307161, -0.01828496, -0.03      ]])
```

The template marker are:

```
array([[ 0.00038417, -0.02389603,  0.00802208],
       [-0.07      , -0.02389603,  0.00802208],
       [ 0.07      , -0.02389603,  0.00802208],
       [ 0.00038417, -0.02389603,  0.08      ],
       [ 0.00038417,  0.07      ,  0.00802208],
       [ 0.00038417, -0.02389603, -0.065     ]])
```

I take the coordinate points of my markers to calculate the transformation matrix like:

```
print 'Calculating the transformation matrix..\n'

n = orig_marker.shape[0]
pad = lambda x: np.hstack([x, np.ones((x.shape[0], 1))])
unpad = lambda x: x[:,:-1]
trans_mat, res, rank, s = np.linalg.lstsq(pad(orig_marker), pad(temp_marker))


transform = lambda x: unpad(np.dot(pad(x), trans_mat))
trans_mat[np.abs(trans_mat) < 1e-10] = 0  # set really small values to zero
print 'trans matrix is:\n', trans_mat
trans_mat_inv = np.linalg.inv(trans_mat)

Out [1]:  trans matrix is [[  3.29770822e-02   1.06840729e-02   1.71325156e-03   0.00000000e+00]
     [ -7.56419706e-03   9.51696607e-03   3.51349962e-02   0.00000000e+00]
     [  5.32353680e-03   2.91946064e-01   8.44071139e-01   0.00000000e+00]
     [  1.96037928e-04  -3.51253282e-02  -3.05335725e-02   1.00000000e+00]]
```

After that I am applying my transformation matrix to my volume grid points by:

```
# apply rotation and scale
transformed_points = np.dot(orig_points, trans_mat[:3, :3].T)
# apply translation
transformed_points += trans_mat[:3, 3]
x_t, y_t, z_t = transformed_points.T
```

, where `orig_points` and `temp_points` are the volume grids of my volumes `x_t, y_t, z_t` are the coordinates of my transformed volume grids.

Since I apply rotation, scaling and translation my volume grids should match. 
unfortunately my volume grid still looks like Figure 2:
[image]

I am almost sure my approach is correct. 
I think the mistake might be in the calculation of the transformation matrix.

Can anyone see what went wrong or where I've made a mistake?

With my own self made translation the result came to look like following:

[image]

Since the result isn't accurate I would prefer a correct calculation of my transformation matrix.

Comment: A couple things would be helpful:  1) Is there a reference for the way you're calculating the transforms? 2) A copy of the data you're using (preferably a simplified example, generated with something like `np.randn(100, 3)`, or the coordinates of the points in the first image) 3) It would also be helpful if the second image showed the reference points in the first image.  That's a short list of things that will make it much easier to tell what is going on with your code.

Comment: Also, it might be easier to visualize if the transform is working in 2d.  You can set one of the axis to all zeros and it should be unaffected, that will give a little more insight into what's happening.

Comment: Regarding:
1) I do have a reference. The calculation was done inspired by a solution given here on stackoverflow (Link follows).
2) Data Structure can now be inverstigated above in the edited original question.
3) Figure 2 was updated by the original marker position (No transformation done to them).

Comment: I found a first mistake. The translation was faced in the opposite direction, so I figured out that, somehow the transformation matrix was calculated mirrored. Therefore I inverted the trans_mat and achieved the a translation in the correct direction (Question is edited).
But still there is something wrong with the transformation matrix. It seems incorrect.

Comment: Looks like the link didn't post.

Comment: Looking at the second image, it looks like it might just be the translation that's incorrect now.  Try subtracting the difference of the mean of both datasets to see if that's the case.

Comment: The Transformation matrix is incorrect indeed. I think the way I calculate it is insufficient (See Figure 3).
 A simple calculation for just a translation is giving me much better results, but still the volume grid is not exactly equal. 

`center1 = np.mean(subj_points, axis=0) 
 center2 = np.mean(temp_points, axis=0)
translation_x_c, translation_y_c, translation_z_c = (center2[0] - center1[0]), (center2[1] - center1[1]), (center2[2] - center1[2])

translate = np.array([translation_x, translation_y, translation_z]) `

Is there a much easier and common way to calculate trans_mat ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157064/discussion-between-daniel-velden-and-user2699).

Comment: I'm still not sure what method you're using to find the transformation, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procrustes_transformation should give an overview of some general methods.